# phalcon -> Fatal error class 'View' not found

Tags: phalcon

When I visit domain.ext/manage
Im getting the error:
Fatal error class 'View' not found

My code:

```
class ManageController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->setRenderLevel(View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
    }
}
```

This is what is causing the problem

> View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making reference to a [constant from Phalcon\Mvc\View](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_View.html#constants). 
Add an "use" to this class in your code.

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;

class ManageController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->setRenderLevel(View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716476/phalcon-how-to-loop-through-associative-array-modelfind-to-output-keys