# phalcon - how to loop through associative (array) model::find(); to output keys

Tags: phalcon

I want to loop through the columns of the model::find results.
What I thought was possible is to cast the returning object to an array to be able to loop throught the columns, but that does not work.

Here is my
Controller code:

```
<?php
class ManageController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->setVar("pages",(array) Pages::find());
    }
}
```

And view code:

```
    {% for key,value in pages %}
    <p>key: {{key}}</p>
    {% endfor%}
```

Any help would be usefull

Comment: The issue with this though is that your adding logic to your controller it might be worth creating a service which does this for you and you can add that service to your dependancy injector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this;

```
<?php
class ManageController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->setVar("pages", Pages::find());
    }
}
```

And view code:

```
{% for page in pages %}
   {# in this case the key is just "0,1,2,3..." #}
   {# so we use the loop index (or loop.index0 for zero based) #}
   <p>This is the page #{{ loop.index }}</p>
   <p>{{ page.title }}</p>
{% endfor%}
```

---

But if you really need to loop through the keys too, use:

```
{% for key, value in items %}
    Key: {{ key }}
    Value: {{ value }}
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: I would add that one can just output page values like: `{{ page.title }}` so there is possibly no need to use key anyway.

Comment: haha another new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970211/phalcon-relationships-not-defined-when-converting-resultset-to-array