# phalcon - Relationships not defined when converting resultset to array?

Tags: phalcon

I have tested it with 2 methods:

The first:

```
class ProjectsController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $row = array();
        $projects = Projects::find();
        foreach ($projects as $project) {
            foreach($project->employees as $employee){
                echo "Employee: " . $employee->name;
            }
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Employee: Admin
```

The second:

```
class ProjectsController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $row = array();
        $projects = Projects::find();
        $projects = $projects->toArray();
        foreach ($projects as $project) {
            foreach($project["employees"] as $employee){
                echo $employee->name;
            }
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Notice: Undefined index: employees in app/controllers/ProjectsController.php on line 10
```

When converting the resultset to array the relationships aren't added to the array, is there a workaround to add it to the array?

The reason I converted the resultset to an array is to edit results for example calculating progress or something like that, without saving it to the database.

Things like this:

```
foreach($projects as &$project){
    //count all the todos.
    $todos = Todos::find("project_id = '".$project["id"]."'");
    $numberOfTodos = $todos->count();

    //count all the todos that are done.
    $todos = Todos::find("project_id = '".$project["id"]."' AND status_id = 9");
    $numberOfDoneTodos = $todos->count();

    $project["percentageDone"] = ($numberOfDoneTodos / $numberOfTodos) * 100;
    var_dump($row);exit;
}
$this->view->setVar("projects",$projects);
```

So I don't have to do calculations on the view side and only have to output it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you convert a result set to an array only scalar values are converted.
But for adding a calculated property to your model there's no need to convert it to an array, you can change or create new properties as you wish and it will only be saved to the database when you call for example `$project->save()` and just properties that match a column name will be stored in the database.

For adding calculated properties I'd recommend you to use the event `afterFetch` that gets fired for each model retrieved from the database:

```
class Projects extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    ...
    public function afterFetch()
    {
        //Adds a calculated property when a project is retrieved from the database
        $totalTodos = Todos::count("project_id = $this->id");
        $completeTodos = Todos::count("project_id = $this->id AND status_id = 9");
        $this->percentageDone = round(($completeTodos / $totalTodos) * 100, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you refer to the documentation? So I can lookup further explanations.

Comment: I have an ->hasManyToMany, how can I check if there are none and echo there are none in the view?

Comment: An unrelated question: how can I access my created dependency injector in an model? That I created in /app/config/services.php